# What is this room with a smiling spider in it?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I saw a room today that I've never seen before, it has a smiling spider surrounded by indestructible blocks in the middle of it, and its icon on the map seems to be a star (it's the icon to the left of my current room on the map.

Has anyone encountered this before? What is it?

[image: Picture of the room][image: the room on the map (to the left of the current room)]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is [an item](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Items) in the middle of the non-destructible stones. More specifically, it's the "Spider Bite".

> Spider Bite - Adds a chance to shoot slowing tears, reducing speed of enemy movement and any projectile fired by them.

The star on the map means that you can pick up the item. If you gain flight, you can fly over the stones and pick it up regularly.

The room is a [Normal Room](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Rooms#Normal_Rooms) in which can rarely spawn an item.